# Creating a list of all possibilities

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a dataframe containing all the possible combinations of A and B in a string with six characters. For example, (A, A, B, B, A, A) and (A, A, B, A, A, A) etc... First, I assigned 6 to the variable n, and then I created a simple vector with A and B.

```
n <- 6
choice <- c("A", "B")
```

Then I used sample() to choose a random letter, with replacement, six times. The sample() part of my code is functioning the way I want it to, but I'm struggling to make a list of all possibilities. Here is what I have so far:

```
list <- rep(list(sample(choices, n, replace = TRUE)))
```

But this only gives me one string. I want it to be however many strings are required to cover every possibility. I thought maybe expand.grid() would help:

```
df <- <- expand.grid(as.character(list))
```

But the problem here is that all strings are identical, so obviously I'm not getting every possibility. Will someone please help me create a list with all possible combinations of A and B, with replacement?

I'm not supposed to use the permutations() function, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track by looking at `expand.grid`.

(Thanks to PierreLapointe for helping me simplify this quite a bit.)

```r
head(expand.grid(replicate(6, c("A", "B"), simplify = FALSE)))
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
# 1    A    A    A    A    A    A
# 2    B    A    A    A    A    A
# 3    A    B    A    A    A    A
# 4    B    B    A    A    A    A
# 5    A    A    B    A    A    A
# 6    B    A    B    A    A    A
```

This first generates a list of arguments to pass to `expand.grid`: six positions, each position with its possible values. Since all six positions happen to contain the same candidate values, we can use `replicate(6, ...)` here. Since `expand.grid` requires a `list` of arguments, we need to tell `replicate` to not simplify to an array (which it defaults to *trying* to do).

Comment: This is the best answer. I would note that `expand.grid(replicate(6, c("A","B"), simplify = FALSE))` works without the `do.call`

Comment: Huh, I've been doing the `do.call(expand.grid, ...)` for so long, I have no idea if it's actually ever behaved differently. Dang, thanks @PierreLapointe.

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` equivalent:

```
librarie(data.table)
CJ(c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"))

   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 1:  A  A  A  A  A  A
 2:  A  A  A  A  A  B
 3:  A  A  A  A  B  A
 4:  A  A  A  A  B  B
 5:  A  A  A  B  A  A
 ....
```

I did not manage to use replicate with `CJ` though.

If you want the vector list:

```
CJ(c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B"),
   c("A","B")) %>%
  apply(.,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ""))
```